# Prove that $\operatorname{span}(V\setminus U) = V$ when $V \neq U$

Tags: vector-spaces

I am having problems with the following problem:

> If $V$ is a given $K$-vector space, and $U \subseteq V$ a subspace with $V \neq U$. Prove that $\operatorname{span}(V\setminus U) = V$.

I think I understand the problem, since if $V \neq U$ then $\dim(U) < \dim(V)$ and if I imagine it in a $2$-dimensional plane it is clear that if I take one line from it, it won't do a thing since I can still find two vectors in $V\setminus U$ that span the whole space $V$, but I have no idea how I can prove it.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $V\setminus U \subset \operatorname{span}(V\setminus U)$, so all that is left to show is that $U \subset \operatorname{span}(V\setminus U)$.

Let $u \in U$ and $v \in V\setminus U$, then $u + v \in V\setminus U$. Also $-v \in V\setminus U$ so $$u = (u + v) + (-v) \in \operatorname{span}(V\setminus U).$$